# Can I use `git checkout --patch` non-interactively?

Tags: git

I want to reset the contents of my working directory to match some revision *without changing the commit my current branch is pointing to*, as `git reset` does. `git checkout --patch` does this, but it does so interactively, requiring me to answer `yes` for every change I want to reset. This is annoying when I'm resetting a lot of changes, in most cases I'd rather just reset everything.

Is there a way to use `git checkout --patch` (or equivalent) non-interactively?

Comment: Does `git checkout <treeish> -- .` do what you want?

Comment: @Chris Does that handle added/removed files? I was under the impression that it didn't.

Comment: I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24518380/1157054), in the general case `git read-tree` can do what you want:

> [`git read-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) `-um` *`commit`*

If, however, you want to be able to checkout/reset a subdirectory instead of the entire tree, you'll need a somewhat more complex command:

> [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) `--cached` *`commit`* `--` *`subdir`* `|` [`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) `-R --index`

Since this command is much longer than the previous, if you plan on using it frequently you'll probably want to set up an alias for it:

```
git config --global alias.reset-checkout '!f() { git diff --cached "$@" | git apply -R --index; }; f'
```

And use like:

```
git reset-checkout 451a9a4 -- path/to/directory
```

Or just:

```
git reset-checkout 451a9a4
```

Answer (score 3):

> [`git read-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html)`-um`*`commit`*

resets the index and worktree to that commit (the `-m` option says to merge what's being read into the index -- with just the one tree and index this is a bit of a degenerate case), the `u` option says to update the worktree when done).

Comment: Git plumbing to the rescue! :-)