# GIT: How to overwrite QA branch with Master, preserving QA branch history?

Tags: git

My goal is that in some point, MASTER (lets say 6.4.3) gets promoted (all stuff goes to a QA branch) to QA, and during this process, I add a four digit to project version, and build it. So, QA advances, producing 6.4.3.1.

This way, I can perform hotfixes on QA branch, and integrate them back to QA (and master, when needed). This will generate a new revision on QA branch, and build lets say 6.4.3.2.

But, time passes, and additions were made to master, and master now is 6.4.9.

So, I need to promote it again to QA, and this must generated 6.4.9.1 package.
BUT all QA changes need to be overwrited by master stuff, and not merged. All that changes were relevant only to 6.4.3.x

All attempts I did resulted in merged operations on pom.xml.
I tried merging and rebase, and also strategies like ours and theirs without any luck.

What I really need is a not-ugly-way of go to master branch, copy -R everything to a /tmp folder, and switch back to QA branch, cp -R from /tmp folder to it, and perform a git add . Then newer files will naturally overwrite old ones.

By doing this, I will end have all new changes from master overwriting old QA changes, that I dont need anymore, but still want to have it on history.

Tks
Marco

ADDED 2014-08-27:

pom.xml on master:

```
<version>1.2.4</version>
<dependency>[6.0.0,)</dependency>
```

pom.xml on qa:

```
<version>1.2.3.1</version>
<dependency>6.0.3</dependency>
```

After the process, I need, on QA:

```
<version>1.2.4.1</version>
<dependency>6.0.5</dependency>
```

The script to generate 1.2.4.1 is working, and the mvn versions:resolve-ranges is working too. Thats why I cant work with already changed files on QA. They need to be replaced with current master changes, so I can make the necessary changes to it.

Comment: I had a similar question a while back: [Can I use `git checkout --patch` non-interactively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515103/can-i-use-git-checkout-patch-non-interactively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution I got, which met perfectly my needs, merging both solutions presented. Tks a lot.

Final git lola:

```
* 782db24 (HEAD, master) 1.2.5
| * d2572c8 (qa) 1.2.4.1
| *   12d4348 Merge branch 'master' into qa
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | 1884a7c release 1.2.4
```

Commands:

```
git checkout qa
git merge -s ours master #(will store this on history, w/o conflicts)
git read-tree -um master #(will replace current merged files with master)
vi pom.xml #(I manually edited to make it 1.2.4.1)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.4.1"
git checkout master
vi pom.xml #(new release, 1.2.5)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.5"
```

Thank both of you guys.

Comment: That's not very good approach. You will have diverged history between branches forever. The better way is to make a QA branch right from master branch as is. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I understand that. But I dont want ever to merge this branch back. What was done in QA branch, stays in QA branch. Features I added to it will be merged both to QA and Master.

Comment: It is not about changes, you could decide it by choosing `ours` or default strategy as per my footnote. It is about maintaining the history graph. Instead of having nearly linear history, you'll get two parallel lines of history which are always running apart.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My point is that QA really diverges, since I have to "fix" the pom.xml file. This "fix" cannot return to master, since I replace dependency ranges to fixed ones (this way, a month from now, I can actually rebuild the package if needed). Other solution would be creating a release.pom.xml file, but it would be odd too to merge it back to master. Any other suggestion to solve this mess?

Comment: Please have a look at my suggested workflow. It merges qa into master using `ours` and it literally means to discard `theirs` (i.e. `qa` branch) changes, while in yours you are merging vice versa (why!?), then as workaround you should replace files back with `read-tree` in a different commit, looks weird, illogical. Moreover, in my workflow the next `qa` just taken from a `master`, no magic merges. It means a "good" code which tested in `master` already is just published as is into `qa`.

Comment: Hummm... Using qa into master with `ours` means 'in case of a messy conflict, use ours'. Right? Then, I will end getting QA pom files, since they are newer than master. I cannot get those back on master. I merge master->qa because I want to maintain history about from where this code came. Then I need to fix any auto-merge possibly made by merge, thats why I use read-tree. Other thing I do my releases off qa branch, not master. My master is my developer branch, if compared to GitFlow. Perhaps thats why it looks inverted. Its is still open.I didnt implemented this yet. Your opinion is relevant.

Comment: No, wrong. `-s ours`: "This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy."

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. Use merges, see the: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . If you want a change in QA, but do not put it back into master, you could merge and then revert it. Makes history more clear.

But if you really wish, use `git merge -s ours master` into the qa branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours origin/qa #discards all qa changes †
vi pom.xml #(I manually edited to make it 1.2.4.1)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.4.1"
# make sure it works, passes all tests, etc and ready to go for QA.
git push origin master:qa #yes, you don't even need to flip branches locally
vi pom.xml #(new release, 1.2.5)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.5"
# continue master development.
```

† You actually should not discard qa changes, as it could be hotfixes/bugfixes tested and accepted by QA and of course should be merged back to master, otherwise same bugs will appear in the next QA, not nice. So normally you should not use `-s ours`.

Exactly the same thing but more difficult and history graph looks worse, however looks as "your way":

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours qa #discards all qa changes
git checkout qa
git merge master # it does fast-forward in fact
vi pom.xml #(I manually edited to make it 1.2.4.1)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.4.1" # committing into `qa` branch
# make sure it works, passes all tests, etc and ready to go for QA.
git checkout  master
vi pom.xml #(new release, 1.2.5)
git add .
git commit . -m "1.2.5" # committing into `master`
# continue master development.
```

Comment: I did -s ours. I ended with my own modifications on QA, since there were changed, and as well, master had advanced. I added 2 sample files on initial question

Comment: lets go from here. I did the same test. I created a 1.2.4 pom and commited it. Then I created QA off of master, and changed it to 1.2.4.1, and commited. Then I moved back to master, and changed it to 1.2.5, and commited. Right now, I have a master ahead of QA. By doing your `-s` suggestion on master, after moving to QA, I still see the same file there, 1.2.4.1, and was expeting 1.2.5. What I am missing?

Comment: Hummm. I guess I found it. We dont change 1.2.4.1 to 1.2.5. Maven does that, from previous 1.2.4. Thats why x.y.z.1 never can came back to master. Makes sense? Still trying to figure out where you and me have divergences about this... and `git commit . -m "1.2.4.1"` cannot be made on master...

Comment: Not sure why you cannot. How do you publish something which was not tested? Normally - you do change, then decide the change is good enough, then publish it to `qa` for further QA process, meanwhile keeping development in master.

Comment: Added "your way" into the answer.

Comment: Perhaps we are facing naming discrepancies among us :-) ... QA branch is meant to be the branch who will generate packages for testing. When it becomes stable, like 1.2.4.9, the package series 1.2.4 will be promoted to production, and all fixes made to it will now be integrated back to master, w/o the changed pom files.

Comment: By saying "cannot" I mean "I dont want to", because of the workflow we are consolidating.

Comment: @Lovato Ok, whatever. But merge+read-tree is weird solution, doesn't make any sense, and there are much simpler and cleaner ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, checkout the QA branch. Then, run `git read-tree -um`*`commit`*. This will effectively "reset" your working tree to the given commit without moving any branch pointers or checking out any commits. After this, you can run `git commit` to commit these changes to the QA branch.

More info: [git-read-tree(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html)

Comment: MAGIC! It worked. You provided me the starting point to achieve my final solution. Tks a lot.