# Git: Make working tree match a reference

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there's a git command for updating the working tree such that it matches a particular reference (e.g. branch).

Essentially, I'm looking for the equivalent to the more manual `git diff -R branch | patch -p1`, that is also a bit more exact - leaving the changes staged as "Changes to be committed" (as git status would put it) and skipping anything like whitespace fixing, etc.

It seems like something `git reset` should do, but I don't see any option for only affecting the working tree without also changing the commit history.

For clarity, I want to do this whilst in the middle of a merge. i.e.

```
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit otherbranch
$ git diff -R branch-i-already-did-the-merge-in | patch -p1
$ git add -A .
$ git commit
```

Comment: Related: [Can I use `git checkout --patch` non-interactively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24515103)

Comment: You keep adding little nuggets of information about your actual problem. It sounds like you want to perform a merge, but during the conflict resolution step, explicitly choose the exact state of a different commit. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK understanding the requirements a bit better now.

You need to use some plumbing commands to accomplish what you want.

git commit-tree will allow you to create a commit from an arbitrary pre-existing tree, with whatever parents you want to specify.  You pass in a commit sha and use ^{tree} to refer to the tree from it.  Parents are passed in by specifying "-p SHA" for each parent.
commit-tree will not update your current head/brach, so we use update-ref for that.
So to create a new commit with tree contents of branch-i-already-did-the-merge-in, with first parent = current HEAD, and 2nd parent = otherbranch, use the following.  Since you are using an already existing tree no whitespace processing should occur.

```
 git update-ref HEAD $(echo "Merge Comment" | git commit-tree  -p HEAD -p otherbranch branch-i-already-did-the-merge-in^{tree} -F -
```

Comment: That's great. I reduced this down a little to `git update-ref HEAD $(git commit-tree "branch-i-already-did-the-merge-in^{tree}" -p HEAD -p otherbranch -m "Merge Comment")`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still somewhat confusing.  You say you want the changes to show up as "changes to be committed" (which means modifying the index), but then you follow it up with "affecting the working tree but not the index" which means "changes not staged for commit"

If you want the files to be staged use this

```
git reset --hard SHA && git reset --soft ORIG_HEAD
```

If you want them to be in working directory only remove "--soft".

```
git reset --hard SHA && git reset ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: Ok - I guess I don't know the right term for "not changing the commit on which the current index is to be based"

Comment: Ok I'm still confused as to what you mean in terms of whitespace, but if you just want to create a merge commit with arbitrary contents you would do `git update-ref HEAD $(echo "Merge Comment" | git commit-tree  -p HEAD -p otherbranch branch-i-already-did-the-merge-in^{tree} -F -`

Comment: Re whitespace: when you do `git add`, then it does whitespace normalization as per the `core.whitespace` parameter. That's an example of the type of thing I don't want, as it can mean the result isn't identical the the branch I'm trying to match.

Comment: I like the merge approach though! If you want to make that another answer, that would definitely be the one I choose to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary index:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/tmptmpindex git reset
GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/tmptmpindex git reset --hard branch .
rm /tmp/tmptmpindex
```

The usual caveats about `reset --hard` being dangerous still apply.

Comment: Hey @charles-bailey - that's an awesome tip! I was looking for something a little more exact, which means I don't need to `git add` them all again (and worry about whitespace "fixing", etc). I did update the question to be more clear on that.

Comment: @ChrisLeishman: Sorry, my mistake, I missed an important `.`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for checkout with path option

You can go to the root path of your repository, and do:

```
git checkout <anotherref> .
```

(Note the dot at the end)
This will set your working copy with the contents of the other ref, be aware any uncommited contents on WC will be overwritten (or checkout could be rejected to avoid overwritting uncommited changes), maybe you want to stash your changes first via *git stash*

Comment: This isn't reliable, it won't remove files that have been added for instance